# GraphiccMagick, how to remove alpha channel

Tags: graphics

Tell me please, how to convert PNG to JNG without alpha channel in GraphicsMagick?

Answer (score 0):

JPG? JPG has no alpha channel, after you convert PNG to JPG, alpha channel will be remove automatically.

Answer (score -4):

If you are trying to remove alpha from png you can use convert (imagemagick):

```
convert in.png -background black -alpha remove -alpha off -resize 1024x1024 out.png
```